# Open all files in a VIM split window view with grep/ack command

Tags: vim, grep, gvim, vimperator, ack

I did a ack-grep on files that contain a string. I then want to open these files in a VIM veritcal split window view. How can this be done via the terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you would need to output the filename and paths of the files that contain the matched text your looking for:

```
ack -ail "my text"
```

a = all files
i = insensitive case
l = output only filesname paths

You combine that line with the following shell expansion script:

```
vim -O $(ack -ial "my text")
```

O = open files in a split window view.
**or**
E = open files in horizontal split view.

The output will be like this:
[image]

Comment: Please note that if you're using `ack -a` to get a list of files, you should probably just be using grep.  In fact, ack 2.0 does away with the `-a` flag.